# Python Decimal gives incorrect result

Tags: python, python-2.7, floating-point, precision

I'm having a problem with the following computation:

```
Decimal(3)*(Decimal(1)/Decimal(3))
```

Instead of returning 1.0, it returns 0.999...

This remains the case no matter how much I increase the `Decimal` module's precision.

Here is the full code:

```
from decimal import Decimal
from decimal import getcontext
getcontext().prec = 800
print Decimal(3)*(Decimal(1)/Decimal(3))
```

Ironically, using the "native" `float` solves the problem:

```
print float(3)*(float(1)/float(3))
```

Needless to say, I'm using `Decimal` here for a more complex computation involving exponentiation of large numbers. After bumping into this problem, I managed to minimize it to the above example.

Comment: A decimal number simply cannot represent a fraction with a denominator of 3. Look at the `fractions` module for precise computation on rational numbers.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of decimal numbers and computers.  There are whole Numeric Methods courses taught to show how to minimize the loss of accuracy when doing multiple computations with decimals in computers.

Comment: @LhasaDad: Like I said, I'm doing a much more complex computation, and the example in my question is only a minimization of the problem. The actual computation is `Decimal(x)*((1+Decimal(y)/Decimal(z))**(Decimal(w)/1000000)-‌​1)`, and the purpose is to emulate a formula implemented on a different (non-pythonic) platform. Given this purpose, I am not allowed (supposed) to optimize this computation for accuracy (or to alter it in any other way for that matter).

Comment: So this is a homework assignment?  What are they trying to teach?  My guess would be they are trying to show you just what you observed rather than for you to trying and find a way to fineness it to get the answer you expect.   They point they are trying to make is that decimal math in a computer is almost always imprecise.   :-)

Comment: @LhasaDad: Work, not homework! And there's no "they" here, I am implementing an emulation in python for some non-pythonic system, I came across this problem and thought I'd ask here for suggestions.

Comment: @goodvibration Sounds good then.  looks like there is good advice coming.

Comment: @LhasaDad: The `Fraction` suggestion is interesting, I'm currently investigating it...

Comment: The result is not as wrong as you pretend : theoretically, the equality [0.999.. = 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...) is exact. It's not the case here because computers don't have an infinite precision. However, when I ask `Decimal(1)-Decimal(3)*(Decimal(1)/Decimal(3))`, I get : `Decimal('1E-28')`. To give you an image : it's like you took 1kg of iron, divided it in three, merge back the three thirds, and realised you lost one neutron (mass : 1.7E-27 kg) during the operation. Are you sure this loss is relevant ?

Comment: @AchilleSalaün: Yes, relevant, because I compare it with the result of the system that I emulate, which must not be larger than this result. Here, however, this condition is not met, since the result of the system (1) is in fact larger than the result of the emulation (0.999), which causes my unit-test to report an error.

Answer (score 6):

Expanding a little on my comment:

A decimal number in Python is literally the kind of number you might write down by hand. Importantly, it doesn't understand the concept of recursion, so an infinitely recurring fraction like `1 / 3` is just represented as `0.333333333333..` up to the point of your precision. When this is multiplied by 3, you get `0.99999..` - which is sensible behaviour, because it can't actually know that that `0.33333333..` was `1 / 3` after it's been truncated. `Decimal`s very often lose precision due to rounding when you divide (in fact when you divide by anything with a factor other than 2 or 5). If being able to do division is crucial, use a `Fraction`, which represents any rational number without loss of any precision by a numerator and denominator:

```
In [1]: from fractions import Fraction

In [2]: Fraction(3) * Fraction(1, 3)
Out[2]: Fraction(1, 1)

In [3]: print(_)
1
```

A Fraction will automatically simplify itself.

With your float, I assume it's just been a matter of luck that the rounding errors have cancelled themselves out. Note that `float` or `Decimal` will probably be good enough unless you need **absolute** precision, in which case I would recommend a `Fraction` (which for example means you could reliably do equality testing). You can always round an ugly number to make it at least look a little prettier:

```
In [4]: "{:.2f}".format(Decimal(3) * (Decimal(1) / Decimal(3)))
Out[4]: '1.00'
```

If you're doing something like a simulation, the difference between `0.9999999` and `1` often won't actually matter much.

Another option is to reshuffle your order of operations so that the numerator is guaranteed to be divisible by the denominator, as seen in 
Anilkumar's answer. This is a good solution if it's possible, but there may well be occasions where you can't do this - eg you're expecting the result to be fractional, or you get the fractional multiplicand from some kind of black box. At this point, it would be possible to track both a `Decimal` numerator and denominator.. and then you realise that that's what the `Fraction` class does, but with less hassle.

Note that you can use a `Fraction` for anything a `Decimal` can do but crucially more. Any representable decimal number is a fraction, too (the mantissa over some power of 10). eg:

```
In [2]: Fraction("3.141")
Out[2]: Fraction(3141, 1000)
```

Naturally, this will lead to some lost performance - Fractions have to keep track of more data, do more calculations and are probably somewhat more abstract.

Looking at your newly provided formula - be wary that when you raise a rational number to the power of a non-integer, the result might not be rational, so you might lose the Fraction somewhere along the way, eg:

```
>>> Fraction(1, 2) ** 4
Fraction(1, 16)
>>> Fraction(1, 2) ** 0.5
0.7071067811865476
```

Although within the context of evaluating a formula it wouldn't make much sense to try and store everything symbolically. This brings us back to the idea of a rough `float` often being good enough. If you really wanted some kind of surd output format, you could give `sympy` a shot:

```
In [1]: from sympy import *

In [2]: sqrt(Integer(1) / Integer(2))
Out[2]: sqrt(2)/2
```

This will of course slow you down even more.

Comment: Thanks, I'm checking your suggestion now; Will update when I'm done.

Comment: Like I said, I'm doing a much more complex computation, and the example in my question is only a minimization of the problem. The actual computation is `Decimal(x)*((1+Decimal(y)/Decimal(z))**(Decimal(w)/1000000)-1)`, and the purpose is to emulate a formula implemented on a different (non-pythonic) platform. Given this purpose, I may not change the order of the formula (or anything else in it), so the reordering suggestion is out of the question for me.

Comment: Thanks. This `Fraction` module seems to have some sort of inaccuracies in certain cases. For example, consider `Fraction(9999999999999999999999999999999223)*(1)**(Fraction(10)/Fraction(9))`, which returns `9999999999999999455752309870428160`. Now of course, if I recognize that the exponent here is 1, then I can easily work-around this specific scenario. However, I cannot start looking up for special cases such as the one in this example. Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: @goodvibration The problem there is that `1 ** Fraction(10, 9)` is a float `1.0` (this is because anything raised to the power of `9/10` might not be a fraction). The whole expression really kind of comes down to `9999999999999999999999999999999223 * 1.0`, which actually doesn't have much to do with `fractions`, but with the nature of floating point numbers. The problem now comes down to representing irrational numbers, where you should either settle on approximation or go for full blown symbolic representation. Of course, in this case `1 ** x` is rational (1) but we can't always know that.

Comment: "anything raised to the power of 9/10 might not be a fraction"? Do you mean "something raised to the power of 9/10 might not be rational"? Anyway, I understand your point, however, `float` is also rational at the end of the day, so why is there a difference here? In any case, it seems that out of all 3 options (`Fraction`, `Decimal` and `float`), it is actually `Decimal` which returns the correct result. So replacing it with `Fraction` helps me in some cases, but creates a problem in others. Any suggestion?

Comment: @goodvibration Yeah, sorry, that's a better phrasing. Note that `float` is rational, but it only represents a tiny subset of the rational numbers - there's plenty of resources to read more on this about the web. Regarding the original example in the question, `Fraction` would be the way to go, but in light of your new specification of retaining precision in exponentation, a high-precision `Decimal` will probably serve you better for speed/precision, or `sympy` for absolute precision.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "high-precision `Decimal`"? I have already tried `Decimal` with arbitrarily large precision, and came across the original problem stated in my question. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: @goodvibration A `Decimal` with high precision will only have small rounding errors - you may need to think about whether the original problem is actually a problem, as `0.99999..` to a massive number of decimal places will be functionally equivalent to `1`. This will be especially so if you use the rounding I suggested with ":.{prec}f". If you really think that you need it to be exactly `1`, the only solution I can bring to mind is symbolic computing, which has plenty of documentation to explore.

Answer (score -1):

I think paranthesis to be changed:

```
from decimal import Decimal
from decimal import getcontext
getcontext().prec = 800
print (Decimal(3)*Decimal(1))/Decimal(3)
```

Output is 1 for me for above one